# Have you an idea to send email in new way?

Tags: php, mysql, email

I created a multi-select drop-down box where dropdown fetches all users who are in my database. I  select all or one particular user and want to send an email.

My issue is I can Fetch all users names in the dropdown but don't known how to fetch selected users email id and send an email to next page?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/87aiG.jpg

**Like:**  at 1st page I select users >> from database >> in multi select dropdown box.
On 2nd page shows TEXTAREA for composing email >> submit btn to send

Why I choose dropdown? Because - to consume very less pages or table to selects Uses. The dropdown is a very short form to select users and send.

Please help.
Or provide the script...

Comment: We need to see your code in order to help you.

Comment: provide your own script!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Comment: @Rick_Jellema I have not this aim. This idea is might for all in future.thats it.

Comment: @Cartor `Please help. Or provide the script...`
This says enough. Try your best friend Google. Also your question is a bit unclear about hwat you really want..

Comment: Someone says this and this website is friend, someone says this and this book is friend and tou saya google is your friend .. still I am confused who is my friend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First file **q1.php** and code for that

```
<?php $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test');  ?>

   <form action='emailScript.php' method='post'>
        <div class="control-group"> 
        <label class="control-label" for="basicinput"> Select Users ID</label> 
         <div class="controls"> 
    <select name="category[]" id="id" class="span8 tip mdb-select colorful-select dropdown-primary" multiple searchable="Search here.." required> 
        <option value=""disabled>Select User Credentials</option> 
        <?php $sql=mysqli_query($con,"select * from Users where Status='1'"); 
        while ($rw=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { ?> 
            <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($rw['Email']);?>">
                <?php echo htmlentities($rw['Full_Name']);?>
                    
                </option> <?php } ?> 
      </select> 
      </div>

     <textarea name='emailText'></textarea>
      </div>

    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send' />
      </form>
```

Second file **emailScript.php**  code is below

```
<?php
   
     //check values are coming here or not
     echo '<pre>';
         print_r($_POST);
      echo '</pre>';

      $emails = $_POST['category'];
      $emailText = $_POST['emailText'];
      foreach($emails as $email){
        //if email sending funciton is set properly then mail will fly
        //:)
         if( mail("$email",'Subject of Email',"$emailText")){
              echo 'Mail Send Successfully';
           }else{
           echo 'ERROR:';
         }
      }

     ?>
```

I hope at least now you come up with good news. :)

I am using xampp with mercury mail server so local meail is sended properly.

[image]

[image]

**Try This with PHPMailer Class**

```
<?php

 //check values are coming here or not
 echo '<pre>';
     print_r($_POST);
  echo '</pre>';
  
            include_once "PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php";
            
            $emails = $_POST['category'];
            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->setFrom('hello@codingpassiveincome.com');
            $mail->Subject = "Please verify email!";
            $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->Body = $_POST['emailText'];
            
            foreach($emails as $email){
                
                $mail->addAddress( $email );
                
                if ($mail->send())
                    $msg = "You have been sent your email!";
                else
                    $msg = "Something wrong happened! Please try again!";
            }

  ?>
  <?php if ($msg != "") echo $msg . "<br><br>" ?>
  <?php if ($msg != "") echo $msg . "<br><br>" ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Er.Amit ! I am run yet this but if you done this in your local host or it works then it's also work for me. But my hosting provider not allowed to send php email since I need to add phpmailler inside. How we add that in this script with attchments.  Could you please update your script. We are indian.

Comment: if you Hosting provider not allow you to send email then I think you won't be able to send email even with the phpmailer script **how ever not sure about that**. You have to either buy mailing feature from hosting or change the hosting service. 

First You try post your code in **phpmailer script** .
StackOverflow community is here to help you not to write code for you. 

Second Indian IT Professional are famous for their hard work 
so be the part of that community and write some code I and we all coder on Stackoverflow will help. 

 :)

Comment: Great then just replace the mail() Function part from the Phpmail finction part and your script will work. If problem come post ur code.

Comment: Error found when I run that with php Mailer pls have a look at this pastebin link to view my error https://pastebin.com/t8q1ZSXn and fix my script pls..

Comment: @Cartor  
I have updated the code kindly see the new block 
**Try This with PHPMailer Class**

Thumbs up if solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks
Happy To help :)
@Cartor

Comment: Yes solve and I tick as thumbs up it might on your reputation. I have basic question that suppose it is possible to which Email I am sending to user, it will also see in users account panel too. Benefits:user can see that what emails he achieve in this months on various subjects? How to we fetch users wish email from database to show his account? Might it is different topic. But short help pls..

Comment: I mean we want to create like this ; suppose I am admin and from my admin panel any email I sent to user it will show users account too. Suppose you are my user and I am your admin. If I send you any email it will show also in your account at specialist page when you will login . Did you get it?

Comment: @Cartor    Yep that is possible. That is simply create a table called `MailSent` in the database 
with the column like **`id`**, **`mailSentTo`**, **`typeOfMail`** and in the previous code in `if` 
condition true block make an `insert` entry to the table and later on the **`admin`** and **`user`** 
account pages simply retrive it.

`mailSentTo`  contains the either the email id or the user id which you sent the email
`typeOfMail`  contains the helping phrase like **"VERIFICANTION MAIL"** or **"FROGET PASSWORD"**

I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Ok! consider I make a table as your command then my code would be as like this ....Did you mean like this?
  `... $mail->addAddress( $email ); 
                if ($mail->send()) $sql = "INSERT INTO MailSent (id, First_Name,, Email) 
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                    $msg = "You have been sent your email!";
                else
                    $msg = "Something wrong happened! Please try again!";
            }
}
  ?>`

Comment: Yep You are right and later on you can reterive the details as per your need and yep you can also increase the information as per your need in table. :)   @Cartor Sorry for late response.

Comment: I write this script but it say wrong..What the correct formate.

Comment: Kindly paste the full Code Like before.in pastebin.

Comment: I use your latest updates phpmailer script but I not get success at my end. My pastebin is https://pastebin.com/8eM1Ydwn please check and you also check that please have a look at this paste bin and you too share pastebin after update. Pastebin is good platform to share codes.

Comment: First of all i think using the script in other page with other logic. 
Second **Check**  On **`On Line 22`** you are getting the list of emails from **database** or by**html** form and also check list of email must be array so that you can use that **emails** variable in `foreach` loop.  If you are retriving the email form database and if it is a single email then no need to use `foreach` loop simple  kindly check the  code at [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/r6SBkc3b)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
please share the error if possible.

Comment: Thank you!  Could you look at this pastebin and fix that? Pls https://pastebin.com/isra8LDs

Answer (score 0):

Hello as here you haven't posted your code or any work which you are trying or working on it.

So at present i can help you by giving idea what you want .

**Step One**

`home.php` in this file you have to write the code for your dropdown select box
which populate the `Name` of user you want to send the email and in **code** part of the `select box` in `<option value="put_user_id">Person Name</option>` put the user id in the option value attribute . You can also make this select box multi select box which you have done as per your question.

**Step Two**

Now when user select some or all user's  and then  `submit` or click on `send mail` button you will simple pass those variable by `GET` or `POST` or `SESSION` 
which ever preferable to you to second page for example call that second page like 
**`mailsend.php`** .

On this page simply you will get two things 
**1** email text you want to send
**2** and `array` of **ID** whose persons name is selected by user to send email.

now you have the id of user you want to send email so simple retrieve  `email` from the database by `foreach` and simple select query with `where` condition or `user_id` then  either store them in `array` again and then write another `foreach` loop to send email.

or within first `foreach` loop when you get the email id of each user in each iteration immediately send email at same time.

**IMPORTANT POINT**

**you said that**: but don't known how to fetch selected users email id and send an email to next page?

To select multiple user in html code you can see this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple)

I hope this will give you at least some idea and i cleared your point.
Feel free to ask i any confusion.

Comment: Thanks for pretty idea , but how to pass multi email I'd of iser to next page!

Comment: Do you want CODE?

Comment: I am giving you my dropdown code where it fetch names from database and also which shows email inside option `value="$email"` if it possible could you help to sharing your script by help compose 'TEXTAREA'' page open text page! Pls? It's means selection of users on first page and compose email on second page. By selecting multi or single users.?

Comment: `<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="basicinput"> Select Users ID</label>
<div class="controls">
<select name="category" id="id" class="span8 tip mdb-select colorful-select dropdown-primary" multiple searchable="Search here.." required>
<option value=""disabled>Select User Credentials</option>
<?php $sql=mysqli_query($con,"select * from Users where Status='1'");
while ($rw=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($rw['Email']);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($rw['Full_Name']);?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
</div></div>`

Comment: what is the logic of using `Status` in sql query?